# how to clear out std and transfer stderr to std?

Tags: bash

I have the following command in a bash script,

> time=$((./a.out) 2>&1)

When run it, there are some printout in std when running a.out alone. How to clear those printout and make `$time` variable only contain execution time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time=$(./a.out 3>&1 1>/dev/null 2>&3)`

This:

1. redirects stderr to an unused stream (3),
2. silences stdout
3. redirects the temporary stream (3) to stdout

This is based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6430/how-to-redirect-stderr-out-to-different-files-and-also-display-in-terminal/6431#6431).

Comment: you r right. There is a compact form that works, too `time=$(./a.out 2>&1 1>/dev/null)`